# Are there any specific advantages of using a blockchain tech in the data tier of an organization from a information security perspective?

Tags: integrity, blockchain

**Blockchain seems to be the most talked about tech topic in *2016*.**

A cryptography powered distributed computing technology that has many potential applications.

Are there any specific ways / guidelines already laid out to leverage blockchain technology for general information security in the data tier of an organization?

Eg: Data integrity etc.

Comment: Don't know of real examples, but block chain seems perfect for logging and non repudiation.

Comment: Yes. It definitely seems to be a great solution where sanctity of the logs is paramount. Even non repudiation in case of some critical infrastructure configuration.

Answer (score 2):

It's now 2018 and blockchain doesn't seem to have slowed down.  One idea that is potentially gaining traction is using major blockchains as a distributed timestamping service: if you insert an assertion into the blockchain (e.g., the SHA-256 of a file), you can prove that you were in possession of the file at the time that block was mined into the blockchain.  (Assuming you do not have compute resources >= 50% of the relevant blockchain.)

Comment: It's one of the only good purposes of the blockchain (more specifically though, an existing, high-capacity one). Good for augmenting a timestamp authority.

Comment: Another thing is that you can't forge a mined block (sticking to the premisse you own less thatn 50% of the blockchain computer power), thus, integrity is guaranteed.

Comment: You can trivially forge a mined block. You just can't insert it in the autoritative chain for long without enough hash power. But then, in an internal setting the company probably has 100% of the hash power under control.